# Download a flutter generated file

Tags: flutter

I want to download(or save to downloads) a pdf file that is generated by flutter using `flutter_html_to_pdf: ^0.5.2`.

Which package or method should I use?

Thanks for the response.

Comment: @see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader & https://medium.com/@petehouston/download-files-in-dart-4f382f86a9f9